# How to render math type tags in reactjs from string?

Tags: reactjs, mathtype

SO, I am trying to render html (mixed. i.e normal plus math type tags) using `react-html-parser`.
It is able to render the normal html but could'nt render the math type tags.

Is there a plugin to render both of them.

Following is my string containing both the content.

`"<p>Math test<br />↵<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msqrt><mn>25</mn></msqrt></math>&nbsp;<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msup><mn>2</mn><mn>3</mn></msup></math>&nbsp;&nbsp;<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mo>&#8746;</mo><mn>2</mn></math>&nbsp;</p>↵"`

Thanks.

Comment: Hello buddy, Have you find any solution for this ?

Comment: yeah. i used react-mathjax-preview to render the whole string. it can render math type  as well as normal HTML tags.